# Dedupe peer dependencies when using "file:" to include local NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I make NPM dedupe peer dependencies of a local NPM package installed using the `file:` pattern in `package.json`? The peer dependencies deduped correctly when the package is installed using `npm install` from the public registry.

[The project in question](https://github.com/joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay) is a Nest.js library published on NPM as `@joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay`. It includes another Nest.js application (in `dev/` directory) as a development tool. The dev app's `package.json` requires the library locally like so:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nestjs-clone-bay": "file:../lib"
  }
}
```

With this setup, it's easy to make some changes and test them immediately by rebuilding the library code and restarting the dev app. However, it appears that this leads to the packages included in the library's `peerDependencies` being installed as duplicates instead of being deduped as they should be.

Result of `npm ls @nestjs/core` for dev app (note that the `@nestjs/core@10.2.6` dependency directly under `nestjs-clone-bay@npm:@joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay@0.0.4 -> ./../lib` is not deduped):

```
dev@0.0.4 /Users/joonas/code/nestjs-clone-bay/dev
├─┬ @joonashak/nestjs-eve-auth@0.3.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.1.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/apollo@12.0.11
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.1.0 deduped
├── @nestjs/core@10.1.0
├─┬ @nestjs/graphql@12.0.11
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.1.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/mongoose@10.0.2
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.1.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express@10.1.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.1.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/testing@10.1.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.1.0 deduped
└─┬ nestjs-clone-bay@npm:@joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay@0.0.4 -> ./../lib
  ├─┬ @joonashak/nestjs-eve-auth@0.3.0
  │ └── @nestjs/core@10.2.6 deduped
  ├─┬ @nestjs/cache-manager@2.1.1
  │ └── @nestjs/core@10.2.6 deduped
  ├── @nestjs/core@10.2.6
  ├─┬ @nestjs/graphql@12.0.11
  │ └── @nestjs/core@10.2.6 deduped
  ├─┬ @nestjs/mongoose@10.0.2
  │ └── @nestjs/core@10.2.6 deduped
  ├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express@10.2.6
  │ └── @nestjs/core@10.2.6 deduped
  └─┬ @nestjs/testing@10.2.6
    └── @nestjs/core@10.2.6 deduped
```

Result of the same command in an app where the library was installed from NPM as usual with `npm i @joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay`:

```
server@0.0.1 /Users/joonas/code/space-major/server
├─┬ @joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay@0.0.4
│ ├─┬ @nestjs/cache-manager@2.2.0
│ │ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @joonashak/nestjs-eve-auth@0.3.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/apollo@12.0.11
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├── @nestjs/core@10.3.0
├─┬ @nestjs/graphql@12.0.11
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/mongoose@10.0.2
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express@10.3.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
└─┬ @nestjs/testing@10.3.0
  └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
```

In the latter, `@nestjs/core@10.3.0` directly under `@joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay@0.0.4` is deduped as it should be and everything works fine (i.e., there is only one instance of Nest.js in the application).

How can I make NPM dedupe the peer dependencies when including the local version of the library? (While having two instances of peer dependencies is obviously wrong anyway, in this particular case some Nest.js features completely break on the dev app because the app itseld and the library are using separate Nest.js instances.)

Answer (score 0):

I found `install-local` to solve this problem. Apparently it actually packages the local library code and uses that. Here's what I did:

1. `npm i -D install-local` to install the tool.
2. `npx install-local -S ..lib` install local lib and save it in `package.json`.

Additionally, I modified my start script to `install-local && nest start --watch --preserveWatchOutput` to load local changes on start (I also rebuild the library on every start). Caveat is that this seems to vary wildly in speed; sometimes `install-local` takes around 30 seconds to complete, sometimes it's almost instant.

`npm ls @nestjs/core` now looks as it should, i.e., only the dev app's direct `@nestjs/core` dependency is not deduped:

```
├─┬ @joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay@0.0.4 extraneous
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @joonashak/nestjs-eve-auth@0.3.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/apollo@12.0.11
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/cache-manager@2.2.0 extraneous
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├── @nestjs/core@10.3.0
├─┬ @nestjs/graphql@12.0.11
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/mongoose@10.0.2
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
├─┬ @nestjs/platform-express@10.3.0
│ └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
└─┬ @nestjs/testing@10.3.0
  └── @nestjs/core@10.3.0 deduped
```