# Configure VS Code to suggest imports from package installed with install-local

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

VS Code does not suggest imports from packages installed with [`install-local`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install-local) even though they are found in `node_modules` directory.

I tried adding the package to `paths` in `tsconfig.json` but it changed nothing. My understanding of VS Code stops short here, however I have an inkling that this might have something to do with `install-local -S` saving the package name in `localDependencies` array in `package.json`. *I believe this is a non-standard field which might cause VS Code to miss the package when resolving auto-import suggestions.*

**What causes these missing imports and how can VS Code be configured to resolve them correctly?**

To give more background, this issue appeared after I figured out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77810807/dedupe-peer-dependencies-when-using-file-to-include-local-npm-package) (TL;DR: using a local reference to a library in `package.json` caused duplicate peer dependencies necessitating the use of `install-local`). Before, when the library was listed in `dependencies` as `"@joonashak/nestjs-clone-bay": "file:../lib"`, import suggestions worked fine in VS Code. I have also confirmed that they appear as usual when the package is installed with `npm install` from NPM repository as one would in normal use.

EDIT: It appears that if I write `import {} from ''` and then start writing the package name between the quotes, VS Code will suggest also the package that was installed with `install-local`. So that part works.

Comment: Take a look at "tsconfig.json" file: is there a `paths` property that includes the correct paths? for example "package-name": ["node_modules/package-name"]

Comment: Yes, as stated in the very beginning of the question, I tried that approach to no avail.